# Организация файловой структуры проекта и сторонние библиотеки C++

Tags: c++, c

При создании небольшого проекта чуть серьёзнее, чем hello world, с использованием одной или нескольких сторонних библиотек и системой сборки CMake, я столкнулся с необходимостью в совете и рекомендации от профессионала, как лучше всего организовать размещение файлов?
Приведу примеры из других языков, чтобы стало немного понятнее, что я имею ввиду:

1. В Python, для работы с библиотеками нужно просто создать виртуальное окружение и с помощью pip установить библиотеку, а интерпретатор всё найдёт самостоятельно, а морочиться с размещением файлов исходного кода - необязательно, python сам всё найдёт в своём виртуальном окружении.
2. В Java немного сложнее и больше возможностей - нужно выбрать систему сборки проектов(Maven,Gradle) и указать зависимости.
3. В Rust есть cargo add и Cargo.toml

Я пробовал сделать всё через vcpkg, но функционал ограничен для unix систем, а так-же настройка, перенос на другие ОС, на другие IDE(с VS 20XX на VSCode) - создаёт очень много проблем на пустом месте.
Смотрел на github, как делают другие и как я понял, они просто создают отдельную папку и туда закидывают все скачанные библиотеки. Насколько это адекватная тема ? Будут ли дальнейшие проблемы с размещением проекта на github, gitlab, файлообменнике из-за большого веса ?

UPD1:
Как насчёт использования Docker ?

Comment: Работал с vcpkg + cmake. Не замечал там каких-то сложностей с разными ОС. Делал проект под WIndows / MacOS, да есть определенные платформозависимые конфиги, но их было минимум и больше обусловлено было тем что делал плагины под Adobe Premier и их особенностями. Кроме vcpkg есть и другие менеджеры пакетов, если он не устраивает

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin вы куда устанавливали папку с исполняемым файлом vcpkg? В любое место на компьютере или прямо в исходный код проекта ?

Comment: в любое место и в окружение добавлял путь к vcpkg

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin папка vcpkg_installed и её вес вас не смущал ?

Comment: А что с ней? Если билдить руками, думаете будет меньше? Альтернатива пакетным менеджерам, если вас в них что-то не устраивает - это билдить все самому, но это еще сложнее.

Comment: Ну используй его как гит модуль, и тогда ничего таскать с собой не нужно будет ...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если что, я не хотел как-то нагрубить, а узнать, может ли папка vcpkg_install как-нибудь помешать ?

Comment: Я и не прочитал это как грубость. А в смысле помешать?